# TestRecorder with MaterialCommand in Toolbar

Tags: codenameone

In a test-class, is there any way to invoke Buttons inside the toolbar, without a name `("")`, which were added like this?

```
getToolbar().addMaterialCommandToRightBar("", FontImage.MATERIAL_PICTURE_AS_PDF, e -> createPDF());
```

Or can I somehow tell the test-class to show a specific form ?(which is happening when I click the button without a label).

The test recorder is not generating any code in that case. It seems that it is only working with buttons, which have a non-empty String as name, as they are simply invoked by

```
clickButtonByLabel("Label");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test recorder was written before the `Toolbar` existed, we tried to update it for the `Toolbar` recently but this proved to be pretty difficult.

We have [this issue](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2038) that covers this bug. As a workaround you can post the command directly in the code of the test.

Comment: The test works fine with directly invoking the commands/methods the toolbar/side menu buttons do, however there are a lot of EDT violation errors thrown, I guess I can disregard them?

Comment: No. I would suggest reviewing them and using callSerially or test class methods so those won't appear.